# Trouble calling a function from a different file: "updateDB.inputFormToDB is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, requirejs

[Github source for reference](https://github.com/R-Dubz/DaycareScheduler/tree/master/Sheets%20API%20Quickstart)

Files where issue exists: **updateDB.js**, **quickstart.js**

Inside **quickstart.js** I have set a variable `updateDB` on line 2:

```
var updateDB = require('./updateDB.js');
```

which I believe refers to my **updateDB.js** file (which is currently living in the same folder).

However later in the file when I try to call a function from **updateDB.js** on line 118:

```
    updateDB.inputFormToDB(rows);
```

I get the error "`updateDB.inputFormToDB is not a function`".

Inside **updateDB.js** I have things set up as follows:

```
var updateDB= function() {
 some function    
 var inputFormToDB = function(parameter) {
     function code
 }
 some function
 some function
};
module.exports = updateDB;
```

Am I missing something to call my function from inside **quickstart.js**??? I feel like I'm making some small mistake somewhere.

Comment: Seems right, `updateDB.inputFormToDB` is not a function, it's a variable inside the `updateDB` function, but it's not chainable ?

Comment: @adeneo by chainable do you mean I should call `updateDb.updateDB.inputFormToDB`? the current call I'm using doesn't work and that's what doesn't make sense because I thought `updateDB.inputFormToDB` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Look at this -> https://jsfiddle.net/baenrsbr/

Comment: @adeneo got it working, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
var updateDB = function() {...}
```

should be

```
var updateDB = {...}
```

like a Object.

e.g.

```
var updateDB = {
  inputFormToDB: function() {...}
}
```

or

```
var updateDB = function() {
  var x = ...

  function inputFormToDB() {...}

  return {
    inputFormToDB: inputFormToDB
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Changed updateDB to act like an object and everything kind of sorted itself out. Had to change the function declarations from `var inputFormToDB = function(...) {...}` to `inputFormToDB: function(...) {...},` after getting some errors, but figured it out. 

It all ended up working, now just have to fix the broken inputFormToDB function because it breaks and says `Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
` -.-

Comment: I did but I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Kkkk ok no problem :)